# Writing tuple values to a file

Tags: python

I have a piece of code

```
# create list of (val, key) tuple pairs
freq_list2 = [(val, key) for key, val in freq_dic.items()]
# sort by val or frequency
freq_list2.sort(reverse=True)
freq_list3 = list(freq_list2)
# display result as top 10 most frequent words
for freq, word in freq_list2:
    print word, freq
freq_list4 =[]
freq_list4=freq_list3[:10]

print freq_list4

f = open("wordfreq.txt", "w")
f.write( str(freq_list4) )
f.close()

output_filename = 'wordfreq.arff'
with open(output_filename,"w") as fp:
        fp.write('''@RELATION wordfrequency

@ATTRIBUTE word string
@ATTRIBUTE frequency numeric

@DATA
''')
```

Essentially I am trying to feed the values from key and val so that @data looks like:

```
@data
word1, 21
word2, 17
```

I'm not very good with this particular area, so any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should begin to do

```
print freq_dic.items()
```

to see the result and conclude on the utility of the first instruction.

2) What's the point of **freq_list3** ? **freq_list3** and **freq_list2** are two distinct objects with the same value. Do you need two objects (that is to say their adresses are different: `id(freq_list3)==id(freq_list2)` is False) of the same value ?

3)

```
freq_list4 =[]
freq_list4=freq_list3[:10]
```

freq_list4 =[]
 is a useless instuction, since **freq_list4** is then re-assign to another object of value  **freq_list3[:10]**

4) If yoiu want to record values of the tuples in a file, you must read these values in the list, that is to say to extract them from the list,

freq_list4[0] is the first tuple in freq_list4

freq_list4[0][0] is the first element of the first tuple in freq_list4
freq_list4[0][1] is the second element of the first tuple in freq_list4

If you iterate on the list:

```
for item in freq_list4:
    print item[0]
    print item[1]
```

or

```
for k,v in freq_list4:
print k
print v
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
for my_tuple in freq_list:
  fp.write("{1:s}, {0:.4f}\n".format(*my_tuple)) # assuming (freq, word) tuples
```

Longer, detailed variant, just in case:

```
for my_tuple in freq_list:
  freq, word = my_tuple # unpacks (0.123, 'the') into word='the' and freq=0.123
  fp.write(word) # 'the'
  fp.write(", ") 
  fp.write("{0:.4f}".format(freq)) # transform the number 0.123 into string '0.123'
  fp.write("\n") # end of line
```